# What meaning is this "leave"?

Tags: secondary-predicates

***The storm left the whole town a wilderness.***

What does this "leave" mean here?

It sounds like the usage of "leave him a billionaire."
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the base sense of *leave* is intransitive, “depart, go away”.

It may also be used transitively, in four senses:

1. With a single complement—the place from which the subject departs. This is treated in traditional grammar as a Direct Object (DO) —

   > I left [<sub>DO</sub>St. Louis] at seven this morning.

   —but it is probably better understood as a Locative Complement (LC).
2. With either one or two complements of which one is obligatory and one is optional. This use is restricted to legacies, what dead people ‘leave’ to their heirs. The obligatory complement is a nominal DO,  and is the legacy which remains after the departure; the optional complement  is an Indirect Object (IO),  the recipient of the DO.

   > He left [<sub>DO</sub>an estate of twenty million dollars].
   >   He left [<sub>iO</sub>me] [<sub>DO</sub>his collection of first editions].

   Like other IOs, this IO may be expressed with a preposition phrase.

   > He left [<sub>DO</sub>his business] [<sub>IO</sub> to his son].
3. With two complements, of which the first, the DO, is a state or condition which the subject effects before departing and the second is an LC telling where the DO is effected.

   > Sherman left [<sub>DO</sub>destruction and misery] [<sub>LC</sub>in his wake].
4. With two complements, of which the first, the DO, is an entity **af**fected by the subject and the second is an Object Complement (OC) describing the DO or attributing to it a state **ef**fected  **(a)** by the subject before departing or **(b)** by the deparature itself. That object complement may be either a nominal or an adjectival construction.

   > His death left [<sub>DO</sub> all of us] [<sub>OC</sub>saddened]. ... *His death caused us to be saddened after it happened.*
   >
   > Sherman’s March to the Sea left [<sub>DO</sub>Georgia] [[<sub>OC</sub>a wasteland].  ... *Sherman's march caused Georgia to be a wasteland after it happened.*

Your sentence is of the fourth type:

> The storm left [<sub>DO</sub>the whole town] [<sub>OC</sub> a wilderness].

Comment: So, *The storm left the city a destructed place* is correct, isn't it? Or *The storm left the city destroyed* is more natural?

Comment: @MaulikV *Destructed* isn't English, because *destruct* is not an English verb. But *The storm left the city a shambles* or *The storm left the city a ruin* or *The storm left the city a mess* are all fine.

Comment: @MaulikV Check out sense 13 in [the link you gave](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/leave_1#leave_1__4).

Comment: @user8153 W e l l ... if you mean that he left you a million dollars in his will, that's not how we'd say it; we'd say *He left me a million dollars* or *His death left me a millionaire.* But if he was your financial advisor, yeah, it would be fine.

Comment: @user8153 Basically, yes, it's the same construction.